# ambiguous access of

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, множественное-наследование

Прошу помочь мне разобраться в проблеме. В своем учебном проекте встретился с такой проблемой, но для вашего удобства перевел её в более простой вид. Ошибка восстановлена абсолютно идентично.
КОД:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

class A
{
public:
    A() { var = 7; };
    ~A() {};

    int var;
};

class B 
{
public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};
    
    std::vector <A> v;
    int var() { return v[0].var; }
};

class C : public A, public  B
{
public:
    C() {};
    ~C() {};
    int b;
};


int main()
{
    C * object = new C;
    std::cout << object->var << std::endl;
    delete object;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
error C2385: ambiguous access of 'var'
note: could be the 'var' in base 'A'
note: or could be the 'var' in base 'B'
```

Я вижу причину в том, что в классе B у меня объявлен метод int var (), ибо если его имя изменить, то всё работает как нужно. Но мне не совсем понятно, почему эта ошибка возникает. Ведь я пишу `std::cout<<object->var` а не `std::cout<<object->var()`.

При этом если поменять `class C : public A, public  B` на `class C : public В, public  A` то в дополнение к первой ошибке появится ещё и :

```
error C3867: 'B::var': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Что для меня тоже не совсем понятно.
Очевидно, что я глупец и не понимаю какой-то простой вещи, поэтому прошу помощи. В моем понимании в данном примере наследование от класса А добавит в дочерний класс переменную `int var`, а наследование от B добавит переменную `v`, которая является вектором типа А, а так же метод var().
Короче говоря, понятно, что ничего не понятно. Объясните, пожалуйста, природу возникновения как первой ошибки, так и второй, очень хочется разобраться. Благодарю!

Comment: А откуда компилятору знать, что вы имеете в виду переменную  `A::var`, а не *адрес* функции `B::var()`?

Comment: Вам же в ошибке все сказано: неоднозначный доступ к var

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это уже второй вопрос — а первый — в неоднозначности имен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При поиске имен откуда компилятору знать, что вы имеете в виду именно переменную `A::var`, а не адрес функции `B::var()`?

Используйте квалифицированное имя, и все будет в порядке:

```
std::cout << object->A::var << std::endl;
```

Так вы уберете неоднозначность.

Понятно, что

```
std::cout << object->B::var << std::endl;
```

не скомпилируется, но это уже будет ошибка компиляции после того, как четко выяснено, что же такое `var`.

Comment: `object->var` не скомпилируется для нестатической функции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это уже второй вопрос — а первый — в неоднозначности имен. Напишите 'std::cout << object->B::var << std::endl;', и он действительно не скомпилируется. Но **неоднозначности не будет**.

Comment: Это понятно. Я имею в вижу, что кажется ничего не мешало бы разрешить такой синтаксис.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat В смысле, без `&`?

Comment: Не, я имею в виду сделать так, чтобы `object->var` без скобок обозначал переменную, а не функцию. Это я к старой формулировке ответа придираюсь. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну есть же варианты, когда нужно имя функции без скобок. Уберем в одном месте — получим в другом...